# Public Shower in Mallorca

Tags: europe, hygiene, mallorca

does anyone have a tip for a public shower on Mallorca? We will travel only in the car. Thank you.

Comment: Are you considering camping in the car? It is probably illegal to do that outside the designated camping sites.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the bigger tourist beaches have public shower heads (in the open air) where you can rinse of sand and suntan lotions, but in addition to that some, including the beach at Playa de Palma

https://www.seemallorca.com/beaches/playa-de-palma-beach-majorca-palma-de-mallorca-661001

Have small toilet and shower blocks located on the promenade.

There is also a shower room at Palma airport.